# How can I use a macro with refined return type inline?

Tags: scala, macros

I have a macro:

```
def f[T]: Any = macro fImpl[T]

 def fImpl[T : context.WeakTypeTag](context: whitebox.Context):
   context.Tree =
 {
   import context.universe._

   q"{ (x: ${weakTypeOf[T]}) => x + 1 }"
 }
```

When I use it as

```
f[Int](1)
```

I see

```
Error:(26, 6) Any does not take parameters
               f[Int](1)
                     ^
```

If I split into two statements,

```
val x = f[Int]

x(1)
```

there are no errors.

Is there a way that I can use the macro `f[Int]` as a function, without writing an auxiliary statement?

Comment: I'm surprised that splitting it into two statements works with whitebox macros. Do you have to have `f` return `Any`?

Comment: If you include the prefix such as `MyMacro.f[Int](1)` the error becomes `too many argument lists for macro method f`. I'm not surprised by the other inference as @TravisBrown.

Comment: Iirc we had a bug for that. If I'm not mistaken, the applicability check is performed solely based on the advertised type of the expression, without doing any macro expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, which is reported in our issue tracker at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7914.

Comment: How much of a blocker is this for you btw? If it's a big problem, we could discuss a workaround, or I might try to fix this issue in spare time in the near future.

Comment: I for one would love to see this fixed.

Comment: Since it's just the applicability check that is too early, I used `q"new { def of(x: ${weakTypeOf[T]}) = x + 1 }"` and `f[Int].of(1)` as a workaround.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577588/is-there-any-workaround-for-scala-bug-si-7914-returning-an-apply-method-from-a for a workaround.