# Is there any workaround for Scala bug SI-7914 - returning an apply method from a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

In our library we have a macro defined like so:

```
def extractNamed[A]: Any = macro NamedExtractSyntax.extractNamedImpl[A]
```

This macro uses its type signature to return an `apply` method whose arguments match the `apply` method of the case class on which it is typed.

The idea is that this allows the user of our library to make use of Scala's named parameters like so:

```
lazy val fruitExtractor = extractNamed[Fruit](
  name = FruitTable.name,
  juiciness = FruitTable.juiciness
)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - it instead returns `error: Any does not take parameters` at compile-time.

It seems like this is caused by [SI-7914](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7914) because it does work if the user explicitly calls apply, i.e.:

```
lazy val fruitExtractor = extractNamed[Fruit].apply(
  name = FruitTable.name,
  juiciness = FruitTable.juiciness
)
```

We can work around this by simply renaming the returned method to something sensible, but is there any other way to work around this without requiring an explicit method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about returning an subclass of `Dynamic` from a macro? Then you could define `applyDynamic` and `applyDynamicNamed` to do what you want. For additional compile-time safety, you can have those `xxxDynamic` methods be macros as well. I just checked and this works exactly with the syntax that you want to have.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The only wrinkle was that scala.language.dynamics needed to be imported at the call site. This can be optionally avoided by making the macro import this:     c.Expr(q"import scala.language.dynamics; new Dynamic { ..$liftedApplyMethods }")